# No cursor in editText under Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an application that uses an internal ime (meaning the ime is just code within the application and not a true ime). I use this ime panel to enter/edit an editText. Everything works fine up to Froyo (I have not tested under Gingerbread). On Honeycomb, however, I can input text and edit it but no cursor or text highlight is displayed! Does anyone know how to work around this? I'd rather not fork my code to a special Honeycomb version just to correct this one problem.

I have explicitly set the xml cursorVisible element to true and then set it to true with setCursorVisible in the code but that doesn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: I have now tried the app in Gingerbread and it works properly there as well. The problem is limited to all honeycomb versions to 3.2.

Comment: Are you setting the input type to 0 (TYPE_NULL)? If so, I do have a workaround that can help you.

Answer (score 7):

Add these attributes to your EditText, to make the blinking cursor black:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

It's needed if you're using the Holo theme.
From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165217/1267112

Comment: Also, android:textCursorDrawable is minimum API 12

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code snip below.

```
public static void setCursorVisible(EditText editText, Context context) {
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
    // sdk
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 12) {// Android 3.1.x  API12
                                                    // HONEYCOMB_MR1
        String filedNameString = "mCursorDrawableRes";
        // mCursorDrawableRes
        Class<? extends EditText> editTextClass = editText.getClass();
        Class<? extends TextView> textViewClass = null;
        if (editTextClass != null) {
            textViewClass = (Class<? extends TextView>) editTextClass
                    .getSuperclass();
        }
        if (textViewClass != null) {
            Field mCursorDrawableField = null;
            try {
                mCursorDrawableField = textViewClass
                        .getDeclaredField(filedNameString);
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.i(TAG, "NoSuchFieldException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mCursorDrawableField != null) {
                mCursorDrawableField.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    mCursorDrawableField.set(editText, 0);

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "IllegalArgumentException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NotFoundException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "IllegalAccessException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```