# Set EditText cursor color

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I am having this issue where I am using the Android's Holo theme on a tablet project. However, I have a fragment on screen which has a white background. I am adding an `EditText` component on this fragment. I've tried to override the theme by setting the background of the Holo.Light theme resources. However, my text cursor (carat) remains white and hence, invisible on screen (I can spot it faintly in the edittext field..).

Does anyone know how I can get EditText to use a darker cursor color? I've tried setting the style of the EditText to `"@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"` with no positive result.

Comment: Just use inside your TextEditText -  android:textCursorDrawable="@color/your_color_choice"

Answer (score 1361, accepted):

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Attribute "textCursorDrawable" is available in API level 12 and higher

Comment: oh man that is SO much more efficient than conjuring up a drawable for the cursor to be black!! I love Android to death but this is such an incredibly bad default behavior... someone really needs to be smacked for it.

Comment: android 3.2 and above .. sucks

Comment: Although if you `target` >3.2 in your manifest you can use it and it will be ignored for lower versions

Comment: in fact I have just noticed that JellyBean 4.2 does not show the cursor if you use the drawable cursor option ! @null is the way to go!

Comment: @AidenFry This seems to work for me on 4.2 JB just fine at the themes level.

Comment: Seems to use the hint color instead if you set it. At least on 4.2. The cursor option has no problems for me from 2.3.3-4.4

Comment: I'm using Android 4.3 on a tablet and it has 2 lines of different color on the sdies of where the blinking should be, that are always visible. Not sure what's up. Looks like it's retaining some of the hint color as a shadow or something.

Comment: That worked OK, but on MEIZU (Android 4.4.2) the cursor became unblinking and grey like frozen or disabled.

Comment: When the EditText has `android:hint` (and `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`), using (`@null`) causes the cursor to show up in the wrong place (in the middle of the hint text). Using [custom drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15431107/56285) works better.

Comment: This does not work in more recent versions of android. Instead it shows a gray cursor and messes with highlight functionality. Use @star18bit 's answer instead.

Comment: result of android:textColorHint="" as the cursor color

Comment: It also changes the text color

Comment: well, it makes the cursor extremely thin, I would go for the custom shape!

Answer (score 618):

In Layout

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    />
```

Then create drawalble xml: color_cursor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```

You have a white color cursor on EditText property.

Comment: Attribute "textCursorDrawable" is only used in API level 12 and higher

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not sure why so many people out there think that setting cursor to "@null" seems like a good idea

Comment: above answer, set textCursorDrawable as @null results look fine, but cursor's orientation does not make sense, however, this answer works really great. Really Thanks

Comment: Can we use same excel with different colors for cursor?

Comment: What if background is white?

Comment: @GregEnnis because that answer makes them save 42 seconds compared to this one

Comment: This IS the solution, thank you @star18bit. I have to mention something though, if the user doesn't care about the color of the cursor, he can set the textCursorDrawable to null and the default one will be displayed, however, for setting the color, this solution is the correct one as some users might be setting @color/cursor_color and seeing nothing, because the attribute textCursorDrawable accepts drawable and not color.

Comment: setting textCursorDrawable as @null will make the color of cursor the same with textColorHint if it is defined so this is the best answer for me :)

Comment: we can control width of the cursor using this solution, but `@null` makes it very thin

Answer (score 94):

It appears as if all the answers go around the bushes.

In your `EditText`, use the property:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"
```

and add the drawable `black_cursor.xml` to your resources, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

This is also the way to create more diverse cursors, if you need.

Comment: This does not work on Android 4.2 Jelly Bean... The cursor disappears, @null is the way to go.

Comment: @Edgar This seems to work for me on 4.2 JB just fine at the themes level.

Comment: Android 4.2.2 works fine. Don't forget to add <solid android:color="#000000"/> in black_cursor.xml

Comment: Attribute "textCursorDrawable" is only used in API level 12 and higher

Answer (score 80):

There is a new way to change cursor color in latest `Appcompact` v21
Just change `colorAccent` in style like this:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->

    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#088FC9</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#088FC9</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <!-- THIS IS WHAT YOU'RE LOOKING FOR -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#0091BC</item> 
</style>
```

Then apply this style on your app theme or activities.

<s>**Update**: this way only works on API 21+</s>  
**Update 2**: I'm not sure the minimum android version that it can work.
 Tested by android version:

```
2.3.7 - didn't work
4.4.4 - worked
5.0 - worked
5.1 - worked
```

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is no. I tested on API 18 device and it doesn't work.

Comment: Working on my Sony Experia. PreLollipop (4.4.4). Also using AppCompat library. :)

Comment: Doesn't work for API 24/Android 7.0. `colorAccent` changes e.g. the line at the bottom of an `EditText` but it doesn't touch the actual cursor color. Oh, and there's no "v21" anymore of course.

Comment: you should not change the accent colour of your application because you want to change the colour of a cursor.

Comment: @oziomajnr, yes, we should apply custom theme to, for instance, fragment, not whole application.

Answer (score 46):

I found the answer :)

I've set the Theme's editText style to:

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditText</item>
```

Then I've used the following drawable to set the cursor:

`

```
<style name="myEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@android:drawable/my_cursor_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:height">40sp</item>
</style>
```

`

**android:textCursorDrawable** is the key here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658772/android-vertical-line-xml might be of use to anyone wanting to make a cursor drawable that is just a vertical line :)

Comment: can you pls tell how can we set the cursor color in programmatically

Comment: I had an issue when I named the item `android:editTextStyle`, but changing it to `editTextStyle` fixed it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34010235/6744473

Answer (score 27):

For anyone that needs to set the `EditText` cursor color dynamically, below you will find two ways to achieve this.

---

First, create your cursor drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    
    <solid android:color="#ff000000" />
    
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    
</shape>
```

Set the cursor drawable resource id to the drawable you created ([source)](//%20https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564)):

```
try {
    Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(yourEditText, R.drawable.cursor);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

---

To just change the color of the default cursor drawable, you can use the following method:

```java
    public static void setTextCursorColor(TextView textView, @ColorInt int color) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            final Drawable drawable = textView.getTextCursorDrawable();
            drawable.setTint(color);
            textView.setTextCursorDrawable(drawable);
        } else try {
            Field fCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            fCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
            int   mCursorDrawableRes = fCursorDrawableRes.getInt(textView);
            Field fEditor            = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
            fEditor.setAccessible(true);
            Object   editor          = fEditor.get(textView);
            Class<?> clazz           = editor.getClass();
            Field    fCursorDrawable = clazz.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawable");
            fCursorDrawable.setAccessible(true);

            Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[2];
            Resources  res       = textView.getContext().getResources();
            drawables[0] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);
            drawables[1] = res.getDrawable(mCursorDrawableRes);
            drawables[0].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            drawables[1].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            fCursorDrawable.set(editor, drawables);
        } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
            if (DEBUG) throw new RuntimeException("can't set text cursor color", throwable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It really bothers me that this works. `AppCompatEditText` already has `setSupportBackgroundTintList`, so wouldn’t it be fairly simple to add something like `setSupportCursorTintList`?

Comment: @Jared Rummler your solution worked for the cursor, but the droplet that appears below the cursor (when you select the text it appears two of them) are still of the original color. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Your 3. approach did not work in Android 9 but fine for below versions.

Answer (score 13):

Late to the party,Here's is my answer,

This is for the people who are *not* looking to change the `colorAccent` in their parent theme,but wants to change `EditText` attributes!

> This answer demos how to change ......
>
> 1. Bottom line color
> 2. Cursor color
> 3. Cursor pointer color (I used my custom image).......... of `EditText` using style applied to the Activity theme.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hey" />
```

**Example:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#8AFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_background</item> // background (bottom line at this case)
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@color/white</item>  // Cursor
    <item name="android:textSelectHandle">@drawable/my_white_icon</item> // For pointer normal state and copy text state
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleLeft">@drawable/my_white_icon</item>
    <item name="android:textSelectHandleRight">@drawable/my_white_icon</item>
</style>
```

Now create a drawable(`edit_text_background`) add a resource xml for the background!You can customize as you want!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-3dp"   
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Now as you did set this style in your Activity theme.

**Example :**

In your Activity you have a theme,set this custom `editText` theme to that.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Your Theme data -->
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditText</item> // inculude this
</style>
```

Comment: ```<item name="editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditText</item> // inculude this``` no effect

Comment: is it AppCompatEditText ?

Comment: oh,I'am wrong. I wrote wrong attr `android:editTextSteyle` ,right attr is `editTextStyle`

Comment: `<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@color/white</item>` doesn't work

Answer (score 10):

Wow I am real late to this party but it has had activity 17 days ago
It would seam we need to consider posting what version of Android we are using for an answer so as of now this answer works with Android 2.1 and above 
Go to RES/VALUES/STYLES and add the lines of code below and your cursor will be black

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">-->
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_Black</item>
    <!--Sets COLOR for the Cursor in EditText  -->
</style>
```

You will need a this line of code in your RES/COLOR folder

```
<color name="color_Black">#000000</color>
```

Why post this late ? It might be nice to consider some form of categories for the many headed monster Android has become!

Comment: Attribute requires API level 21 not 7 (2.1)

Answer (score 9):

```
Edittext cursor color you want changes your color.
   <EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    />
```

Then create drawalble xml: `color_cursor`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 7):

For me I modified both the AppTheme and a value colors.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

Here is the colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="yellow">#B7EC2A</color>
</resources>
```

I took out the android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null that I placed inside the editText style. When I tried using this, the colors would not change.

Comment: Yes that works but then you also change other theme elements when all you might need is to change the cursor color.

Answer (score 7):

**Use this**

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@color/white"
```

Comment: The cursor disappears in my device, so use a drawable instead of direct set the color.

Comment: this is useful if you want to hide the cursor, if you say that you'll probably get more votes!

Comment: This is not proper solution. This will disappeared the cursor before typing and between typing it's not proper to show if we change color.

Answer (score 6):

We can do it in meterial theme as following:

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">#ff0000</item>
    ...
</style>
```

And if you want to change checkbox and radio colors too, add the following line:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
```

I've tested in Android API 21+

Answer (score 5):

The only valid answer should be to change the theme of the activity: 
`<item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>`
You should not use the `android:textCursorDrawable` to `@null` because this only concerns the cursor itself but not the pin below the cursor if you want to drag that cursor. The theming solution is the most serious one.

Answer (score 5):

Here @Jared Rummler's programatic setCursorDrawableColor() version adapted to work also on Android 9 Pie.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"JavaReflectionMemberAccess", "deprecation"})
public static void setCursorDrawableColor(EditText editText, int color) {

    try {
        Field cursorDrawableResField = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        cursorDrawableResField.setAccessible(true);
        int cursorDrawableRes = cursorDrawableResField.getInt(editText);
        Field editorField = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
        editorField.setAccessible(true);
        Object editor = editorField.get(editText);
        Class<?> clazz = editor.getClass();
        Resources res = editText.getContext().getResources();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            Field drawableForCursorField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mDrawableForCursor");
            drawableForCursorField.setAccessible(true);
            Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(cursorDrawableRes);
            drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            drawableForCursorField.set(editor, drawable);
        } else {
            Field cursorDrawableField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawable");
            cursorDrawableField.setAccessible(true);
            Drawable[] drawables = new Drawable[2];
            drawables[0] = res.getDrawable(cursorDrawableRes);
            drawables[1] = res.getDrawable(cursorDrawableRes);
            drawables[0].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            drawables[1].setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            cursorDrawableField.set(editor, drawables);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.w(TAG, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mDrawableForCursor ` on Android 9.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Answer (score 5):

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> -- change this one
</style>
```

Go to styles.xml and change the color accent and this will influence the cursor from the edittext box

Answer (score 4):

that's called `colorAccent` in Android.

go to res -> values -> styles.xml add

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
```

if not exists.

Answer (score 3):

**editcolor.xml**

`android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/editcolor"`

In xml file set color code of `edittext` background color

Comment: Just remove the corsor which is blinking in edittext

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of time spent trying all these technique in a Dialog, I finally had this idea : attach the theme to the Dialog itself and not to the TextInputLayout.

```
<style name="AppTheme_Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

inside onCreate :

public class myDialog extends Dialog {

```
private Activity activity;
private someVars;

public PopupFeedBack(Activity activity){
    super(activity, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog);
    setContentView(R.layout.myView);
    ....}}
```

cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to your colorAccent in your current Activity/fragment/Dialog, defined in Styles... ;)
cursor color is related to it.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution would be to go to res>values>colors.xml in your project folder and edit the value of the color accent to the color you prefer

```
<color name="colorAccent">#000000</color>
```

The code above changes your cursor to black.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

In API 21 and above:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout                
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:theme="@style/CursorColor">

// In colors.xml
<style name="CursorColor">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>>
```

Comment: The most simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

Its even easier than that.

```
<style name="MyTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">#000000</item>
</style>
```

This works in ICS and beyond. I haven't tested it in other versions.

Comment: beware, if you are going to apply this style to your EditText(this does not have a parent style, which should be the default pertaining to your theme), you will loose all other styling that comes from the Holo Theme.

Comment: Isn't it the same as "@null" value ?

Comment: you can add a style juste to a view, which overrides the activity's theme.

Answer (score 1):

are you want specific color you must use **AppCompatEditText** then backround set **null**

works for me

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:background="@null"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/cursorColor"/>
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mediavrog/9970ad4f97a309542e52)

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved it

Step1: Update the latest material

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Step2: type reference TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense, Any...

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/app_color_main</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/app_color_main</item>
        <item name="android:theme">@style/exampleCursor</item>
    </style>
```

Step3: [important to change cursor color] - set colorControlActivated property to desired cursor color

```
    <style name="exampleCursor" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/app_color_main</item>
    </style>
```

more detail [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/820#issuecomment-614095900):

Answer (score 1):

2023 - `Compose` Edition

You can change the cursor color with `cursorBrush`.

Sample Usage

```
BasicTextField(
            
            ...
            cursorBrush = SolidColor(Transparent),
            ...
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#36f0ff</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#007781</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

change t he color of colorAccent in styles.xm, that's it simple

Answer (score 0):

If using style and implement

> colorControlActivate

replace its value other that color/white.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set cursor color since 1.10.0 version.

[Developer quote:](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/3345#issuecomment-1507481650)

> It's fixed in [c598ccd](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/c598ccd51ec68828f241301455fb3f59369fe467).
> We added an attribute and a setter to set the cursor color under errors.
> The change is supposed to be published with upcoming 1.10.0-alpha02.

Add the following code to your TextInputLayout style:

```xml
<item name="cursorErrorColor">@color/error_color</item>
<item name="cursorColor">@color/accent_color</item>
```

or to your TextInputLayout view:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cursorErrorColor="@color/error_color"
app:cursorColor="@color/accent_color"
...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

Add this in styles and then in the Edittext set the theme as follows:

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

And thats it!

Answer (score -2):

you can use code below in layout

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/black
```