# EditText cursor not visible in Android 3.0

Tags: android

I am working on Android 3.0. I am using an `EditText` that has a transparent background . The `EditText` is placed on a layout having a white background. As a result the `EditText` cursor is not visible (I assume the cursor is white by default) . After going through your forum I found out a solution that says I have to create my own cursor drawable using `styles.xml`.

But to my dismay, the `cursorDrawable` parameter is available only in Android 3.1. But I have to work on 3.0 and above.

Is there any solution?

Comment: and also snapshot (if possible)

Comment: if you can't change the cursor color, then change the white background of the layout.

Comment: i have changed the background to a darker color.Now the cursor is visible.

Comment: We cant proceed if u dont post your code...

Answer (score 8):

Add these attributes to your EditText, to make the blinking cursor black:

```
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

It's needed if you're using the Holo theme. And it will work on older Android versions if you set the minSDK value in the AndroidManifest.xml

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165217/1267112

Comment: textCursorDrawable is only available in 3.1, not 3.0 as the OP needs

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine But , Cursor not blinking in my 3.1 device

Answer (score 0):

Setting minimum width (5dp) to edit text while using wrap_text as layout_width will show the cursor when the edittext's background is transparent.