# Change the color of the cursor of an EditText in Android across all the sdk

Tags: android, android-edittext, text-cursor

I want to change the android's edittext cursor color on all devices. How do I do that?

Answer (score 19):

i had to use a drawable like this:

mycursor.xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:width="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/> 
<!--make sure its a solid tag not stroke or it wont work -->
    </shape>
```

in my edit text i set the cursor drawable attributes like this:

```
                            <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_details"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:cursorVisible="true"
                           android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/mycursor"  
                            />
```

Answer (score 8):

The way to get it across all platforms is as such.

1 - Open your layout.xml in your layout folder.
Find the edit text and set

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

this will set the cursor for devices lower that os version 11

2 - Create your cursor_drawable.xml in the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

3 - Create a folder layout-v11

4 - Copy your layout.xml into the layout-v11

5 - Find your edit text and set android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_drawable"

This will make a cursor be shown on all devices and OS.

Comment: Hi aiden, im also having same issue.. im developing app with 2.2 api build. when i  do as you said im getting error in xml file at android:textCursorDrawable has no reference ... Pls let me know how to solve it....

Comment: That also requires the Holo Theme, and hence Android 4.0. Did you read that one?

Comment: I couldn't make it work nicely if gravity is set to right and hint is set to some value. Initially cursor is in front of hint and can't be moved/aligned to the right until you start typing then hint dissapears and cursor gets well aligned to the right.

Comment: It seems you need     <solid android:color="@color/black"/> to show the cursor

Comment: Replace stroke by solid

Answer (score 7):

Assign `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` and set `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Answer (score 1):

Create drawalble xml: edtcolor_cursor

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <size android:width="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
    </shape>

<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edtcolor_cursor"
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color) to this link. 
You can try this to

```
android:textCursorDrawable
```

Comment: I want that across all the versions. This attribute is avail only after Android 3.0