# change edittext cursor color

Tags: android, user-interface

How can I change `EditText's` *cursor's color* programmatically ?

In android 4.0 and above, *cursor color* is white. and if `EditText`s background is also white, it becomes invisible.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

In your EditText properties, there is an attribute `android:textCursorDrawable`

Now set it to **@null** like,

`android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

So now your EditText Cursor is same as your EditText TextColor.

Reference From [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

Comment: I need it programmatically, not xml based

Comment: @Adem if you set this in the XML you can set any color programatically as the text color.

Comment: This also doesn't work for the question asked, which is how to set it *programatically*.

Comment: @Adrian - I know the rules of Stack. But just consider the edited time of question also. Because it edited `"programatically"` after my answer. Anyway :-)

Comment: You can set the text color programmatically, which changes the cursor color at run time, programmatically, have some critical thinking skills.

Comment: People who don't accept a good answer, should be lose reputation or at least shotted.

Comment: The OP wants to do it via by code and not xml layouts so therefore this is not the correct answer

Comment: @user370305 this makes the cursor look very thin and almost non visible

Answer (score 30):

I found a way to fix this. It is not the greatest solution, but it works.

Unfortunately, I can only use static color for the cursor color.

First, I define a black cursor in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>
    <size android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Next I define a sample EditText in layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/blackpipe"
         >
    </EditText>
```

When I want to create an EditText at runtime, I use this:

```
AttributeSet editText30AttributeSet = null;
int res = getResources().getIdentifier("edit30", "layout", getPackageName());//edit30 is EditText layout
XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(res);
int state=0;
do {
    try {
        state = parser.next();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       
    if (state == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        if (parser.getName().equals("EditText")) {
            editText30AttributeSet = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
            break;
        }
    }
} while(state != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT);
EditText view = new EditText(getContext(),editText30AttributeSet);
```

Now you have an EditText view that has a black cursor. Maybe somebody can improve on my solution so that the cursor can be changed at runtime.

Comment: Great job, thank you! Works like a charm for custom EditText component.

Answer (score 17):

Here is, what I think, a better solution than what @Adem posted.

Java:

```
try {
    // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564
    Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(yourEditText, R.drawable.cursor);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ff000000" />

    <size android:width="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 9):

improving on Jared Rummler's answer

Java:

```
try {
    // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L562-564
    Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(yourEditText, R.drawable.custom_cursor);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

create custom_cursor.xml in res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#ff000000" />

    <size android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

XML:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
     >
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 8):

What about the `styles.xml` using AppCompat-v7?

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/accentColor</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accentColor</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
```

Works for me (this example is simplistic).

Comment: Do these accents apply for EditText cursors on pre-Lollipop devices for you?

Comment: No, it then takes the default system's cursor (sadly). Good answers have been posted since, way more complete.

Answer (score 3):

You may Set the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` that will result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Attribute `textCursorDrawable` is available in API level 12 and higher...

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Set Via AppTheme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"><!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinner_style</item>
    <!--Add This-->
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/EdittextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<!--New EditText Style-->
<style name="EdittextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/editTextBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/editTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <!--<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/abc_text_cursor_material</item>-->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, here's the final version - doesn't need the XML and works as @null but programmatically:

```
try {
    Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set((TextView)yourEditText, 0);
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

The only problem is that it may stop working one day with some new version of Android.

PS I tested it on 4.1.2 to 5.1.