# how to give different color for cursor and text of an EditText in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

How can i create a cursor similar to the image which have different textcolor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649234/change-edittext-cursor-color   check this

Comment: @Blackbelt in that i can get only same clolor for cursor and text i need different color for those

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00ff00"/>
    <size android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**EditText in layouts**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/greencursor"
         >
    </EditText>
```

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Answer (score 2):

What about the styles.xml ?

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/accentColor</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accentColor</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accentColor</item>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649234/change-edittext-cursor-color   you are just copy and pasted the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:textCursorDrawable` to `@null` like,

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

Now your `EditText` Cursor is same as your EditText TextColor.

**UPDATE:**

Then you can use the property: `android:textColor` to set the color you want for your cursor.

Reference: [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color).

Comment: i need different color