# Change the color of the cursor android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to change the green of the cursor into grey. But it stays green. Any ideas?

```
<EditText
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/grey"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"/>
```

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40889531/1276636) of mine helps you change the colour of handles. Please refer to it.

Comment: your cursor color has changed correctly, but you want change bubble color, see duplicate question to get how to change color of bubble with Accent color

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19155021/5733111)

Answer (score 0):

Use this property in `EditText` in the xml :

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your AppTheme in styles.xml but it will also change color of other EditText elements (cursor and bottom line).

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/grey</item>
```