# android:textCursorDrawable unknown

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a white EditText and in Android 3.1 and above the cursor doesn't show (because it's also white). For info, I use

```
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
```

I read on this post [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color/9165217#9165217) that the solution was to set the textCursorDrawable attribute to "@null" which I have tried, but I can't use it because it says that the attribute is unknown.

I have my SDKs set in the AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
```

but it still won't recognise android:textCursorDrawable

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have not changed the build target for your application. That is why eclipse is not detecting `android:textCursorDrawable`

Right click on project -> Properties-> Android -> Build Target -> select api level 12 or greater

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Apologies for the delay in responding but other priorities took over.

I don't use Eclipse, I use Intellij Idea. For the record, the same solution can be applied under Intellij Idea:
File -> Project Structure and set the Module SDK under the dependencies tab.