# EditText cursor is invisible in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an `EditText` input in Android 4.0 and the Cursor is not showing inside it.

What can make the cursor not appear in the input field?

Comment: I had this problem, I think it was related to the theme I had set on the project, sorry, it's been ages.

Comment: @alex as i see other edit-text cursor are showing as in creating a new contacts etc
how there cursor are showing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9165217/3000919 provides the correct answer with a clear explanation.

Answer (score 60):

Make `android:cursorVisible="true"`

and

If you have used `android:textColor` then set the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null`.

Happy coding ;)

Comment: android:textCursorDrawable  is for API levels 12 and above. Works like a charm though. Any solution for lower versions?

Comment: android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:hint="Amount">
                <requestFocus/>

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because it solved my issue (textCursorDrawable), but your reason for it is slightly erroneous. textCursorDrawable="@null" will make your cursor color the same as your textColor, but you don't need to use android:textColor for it to work. textCursorDrawable solves the cursor issue if the reason the cursor can't be seen is because it's the same color as the EditText background (generally white).

Comment: You are awesome, that was the issue I was stuck in android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem but it was because the cursor is actually white and I had a white background. I needed to be able to change the cursor to black in code somehow and used this approach.

I created a layout resource called textbox.axml which contained this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a template"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```

I then applied this layout in code (C# because I am using Xamarin) thus

```
    EditText txtCompletionDate = (EditText)LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textbox, null);
```

but it is similar in Java.

Comment: To use this answer in Android, just add the android:textCursorDrawable="@null" (seen at the end of the EditText in the answer).

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. android:textCursorDrawable="@null".  its work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Add this line for your edit text in the xml file.

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

Answer (score 4):

I happened quite same problem - cursor was showing up only after user types some characters. I tried solutions listed here, but without any success on my device. What actually work for me, is setting blank text to my edittext:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editText.setText("");
```

This "fakes" the user input, and cursor appears.

Comment: thks, this is the only answer solved my problem, it takes me hours. i think it's mightbe a bug of edittext

Comment: Actually it didn't work for me, but `editText.setText(" ")` (with a _space_) did

Comment: I set the hint instead to a whitespace. I know it's not an option for everyone but at least you won't have to set the text to a whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I was using the AppCompat theme, but I had some custom view classes that extended EditText that needed to extend AppCompatEditText in order for the AppCompat style to be applied correctly.

Comment: To me, this seems to be the correct answer. Setting the cursorDrawable to @null also changes the cursor's appearance, it looks very thin in my case. Changing from EditText to AppCompatEditText fixes the problem *and* displays the cursor correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line for your edit text  in the xml file.

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding my own personal fix to anyone it might help. I had tried everything here but forcing `android:background="@null"` was causing a very tiny cursor only at the end of my right aligned `TextEdit` (it was right working fine elsewhere).

Simply adding `android:padding="1dp"` in my `TextEdit` solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, here's the actual line
  android:textCursorDrawable="@null"

```
 <EditText
               android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:id="@+id/edSMobile"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:background="@drawable/edit_corner"                    
                android:inputType="phone" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing it to happen to me.

You need to inherit it from the application's theme. I'm not sure what the line item needs to be exactly, but `android:Theme` has it so inheriting that will do that trick.

Using the default `AppBaseTheme` will work (it has `android:Theme.Light` as it's parent).

To use `AppBaseTheme` put `android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"` into your application tag in the manifest. You can also use a custom style and multiple levels of inheritance so long as one of them has `parent="android:Theme"` in the style tag.Like I said it may be possible to have it without that, just using certain line item(s) but I don't know what those would be.

If you don't need a custom theme you can just use

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme"`

Answer (score 0):

In My case the cursor is visible if user language is English but if he change his language to Arabic then its not visible.

To fix this I have created on custom drawable for cursor.

Cursur shap at drawable/black_cursor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#a8a8a8"/><!-- This is the exact color of android edit text Hint -->
    <size android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Edit Text:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

If the EditText has a Background drawable with a border, the cursor is displaying in the border and appears to be invisible. To rectify the problem set padding in the EditText to a small amount e.g. 5dp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the cursor then just do

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null".
```