# No cursor in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor-position

When I touch my EditText, the virtual keyboard opens and I can edit the text, but I have no cursor that tells me where the next char would be, and no blue rectangular shape that would tell me if I touched the EditText or what EditText was touched.

The code is:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FCFCFC"
        android:hint="\?"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
```

What did I do wrong or what do I need to add?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: `Caret`, `Cursor` are the words for * vertical line. * :)

Comment: I use @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme. android:cursorVisible="true" didn't work and I have no usage for caret.

Comment: If it interest anyone - following this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38430075/715439) made the cursor visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null should result in the use of android:textColor as the cursor color.

it will work

Comment: It doesn't, even after I specify android:cursorVisible="true"

Comment: Check out my edited code @Ran i hope it will useful to you