# How to change searchView's style of actionBarCompat?

Tags: android, searchview, actionview, android-actionbar-compat

How can i Change the style of textView inside the search's actionView ??

I managed to change the icons and background of it , but I want to change cursor's color and "Texthighlight" of listview.

I used `android:textCursorDrawable=@null` in my app's theme ( and another styles that changes actionview's style), but it seems any changes to the theme doesn't effect on ActionBarcompat's Searchview.

I use open source support library ( imported the library to eclipse then added it to my app).

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Changing the cursor color in SearchView without ActionBarSherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705185/changing-the-cursor-color-in-searchview-without-actionbarsherlock)

Summary: You have to use [Java reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html) to access [mCursorDrawableRes](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7d1c55fad8194e2c82f5f88f98ab5569f9c52ab9/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) in TextView and set it to 0.