# Android Lollipop Toolbar Searchview cursor / caret color

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, theming

**Hello,**

My question is simple; how can I change the cursor/caret color for my **SearchView** when using the **Toolbar** from Androids Support Library?

It works by setting:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">#ffffff</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#ffffff</item>
```

**However,** the side effect then is that all my other **EditText** will pick up this color, which is **not** what I want.

Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182516.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style the cursor color of SearchView under AppCompat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730253/how-to-style-the-cursor-color-of-searchview-under-appcompat)