# How to change this symbol place to the right of searchview?

Tags: java, android

How to solve this problem? I want to change its place to the right!
take a look at the screenshot to understand what I mean.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YewTI.png)

Comment: That looks like the text cursor. If you are looking to change the color, you would handle that through your theme. The details will vary by what theme family you are using (e.g., `colorAccent` for themes based on `Theme.AppCompat`).

Comment: @CommonsWare No, I want to change | to the right of searchview.

Comment: hope this will be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287938/change-cursor-color-of-searchview

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to place the cursor at the end of text
Kotlin:

editText.setSelection(editText.length())//placing cursor at the end of the text
Java:

editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());