# SearchView does not show blinking cursor when in focus

Tags: android, xml, searchview

I have a `SearchView` button in my `Toolbar` and whenever I click the button, the `SearchView` expands and the keyboard pops up like it should. However, when it is in this initial state, there is no blinking cursor. I can type something and it will display the inputted text but it won't show the cursor. But once I touch the text area, *then* it displays the blinking cursor.

So how can I get `SearchView` to display the blinking cursor when the icon is clicked, without ever touching the text area?

By touching the "text area" I mean the area pointed by the arrow just to avoid confusion:

[image]

And here is my SearchView xml code if it's any help:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_view_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:queryHint="@string/search">

</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
```

I'm accessing the `SearchView` as a `MenuItem` object in `OnCreateOptionsMenu()`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `cursor` isn't visible because it has the same color with the `actionbar`.
Try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705185/changing-the-cursor-color-in-searchview-without-actionbarsherlock/19796417#19796417)

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) ((AppCompatActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.search_view);
final EditText e = (EditText) sitesSearchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
try {
   Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
   mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
   mCursorDrawableRes.set(e, 0); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
} catch (Exception ex) {}
```

** **EDIT** **

try this

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
```

Comment: Then why is it that when I touch the text area, the cursor becomes visible? The cursor color becomes the color set in colorAccent in my style theme.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar2" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/main_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/main_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`enter code here`
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/Widget.SearchView</item>
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).