# EditText cursor is not visible on Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

The EditText cursor is visible on Android 4.0 or a lower version, but in the Android 5.0 (Lollipop) version it is not showing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe your cursor has the same colour as background? You can change your cursor's colour to something other that background colour and check.

Comment: Could you please post your xml here

Comment: I've solved this problem to do like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527420/custom-cursor-color-in-searchview).

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:cursorVisible="true"`and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your XML file.

Example:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/textLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Sometimes EditText requires focus to show the cursor so maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem to do it like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527420/custom-cursor-color-in-searchview).

The problem is that I was using it like this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:textCursorDrawable="#666666"/>
```

If you are going to use textCursorDrawable, you should use drawable res to the value like this:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/red_cursor"
```