# Changing AppCompat's SearchView colorAccent

Tags: android, android-styles, android-toolbar, android-search

I know this topic has been asked previously but most of the answers provide a programatic solution which is not very up to date.

I have a `SearchView` inside `Toolbar`, I need to modify it's appearance a bit, here's my style file

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.XYZ" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#29abbd</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00838f</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#29abbd</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#29abbd</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/Theme.XYZ.SearchView</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Theme.XYZ.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
        <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This does not work, the `SearchView` is not assigned with the custom close icon and the `colorAccent` is the color of the main theme.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What color should be changed? The textcolor, background or something else?

Comment: The cursor's color, which is controlled by the colorAccent.

Comment: Maybe it is because you are declaring two parents. Can you change the searchview style name to `MySearchViewStyle`? And test if the close icon changes? And I think the cursor color is controlled by another field and cannot be overruled like you do, I guess. Give it a try :)

Comment: I've tried, the icon does not change.

Comment: Do you apply the theme to the activity where the searchview should be displayed? Regarding the cursor you may have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527420/custom-cursor-color-in-searchview

Comment: Yes, the theme itself (Theme.XYZ) is being applied, thanks, will have a look.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with using Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView instead if Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView and using android:textCursorDrawable.
Put it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730253/how-to-style-the-cursor-color-of-searchview-under-appcompat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting here my solution, although it defines a style to AutoCompleteTextView instead of SearchView directly

```
<style name="Theme.XYZ" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#29abbd</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00838f</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#29abbd</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#29abbd</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/XYZSearchView</item>


    </style>


    <style name="XYZSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/white_cursor</item>
    </style>
```