# EditText cursor becomes invisible in JellyBean

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In my app, I have an edit text with properties:

`android:inputType="none"` and `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

It's because I have defined my own buttons to enter input (buttons, not custom keyboard). I have used

`editText.requestFocus()`

to make the cursor visible. Upto to android 4.0.4, the cursor is visible and not in phones running Jelly Bean. The cursor isn't visible but I'm able touch and enter text between characters ( using `editText.getSelectionStart()` ).

What has changed in Jelly Bean? How do I make the cursor visible?

**Edit:**
`android:cursorVisible="true"` isn't helping.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Removing 
`android:textIsSelectable="true` (text is selectable even without this)

and adding

`android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` fixed the issue.

Comment: The cursor could be invisible because it blends with the background colour. The `null` above forces it to use the `android:textColor`

Answer (score 11):

In `Jellybeans`, it happens if you set background to `editText`.

To show cursor in `editText`, just use `android:textCursorDrawable="@null" and android:textColor="@color/someColor"`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: I need to be able to set cursor. Won't this prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Setting     `android:textCursorDrawable="@android:drawable/my_cursor_drawabl"` as shown below.

Theme's editText style :

```
<item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditText</item>
```

Following drawable to set the cursor:for android:textCursorDrawable property of edit-text

```
<style name="myEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@android:drawable/my_cursor_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:height">45sp</item>
</style>
```

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color/7238526#7238526)

Comment: I have added the <style> to styles.xml. Where must I add the <item>? And what must be in drawable/color_cursor.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the background attribute from the parent.
e.g
        android:background="#FFFFFF"