# Not seeing cursor on the text field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Hi I'm not able to see a caret sign on the text field. Even though I can type in it, not having cursor is misleading.

I've tried this on API15 to API19

The textfield is like this:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            style="@style/LoginEditText"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pwd"
            />

<style name="LoginEditText" parent="EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:autoText">false</item>
    <item name="android:capitalize">none</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="EditText" parent="Global">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
</style>
<style name="Global">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
<color name="text">#ff000000</color>
```

**Settings in my theme**

```
<style name="App_EditTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dip</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

I want the background of the edittextfield to be white. So maybe the cursor is being white as well...I'm not sure.

If I remove `<item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>` then I do see the cursor, however, the background is no longer white as I wanted it to be white.

Comment: You mean the cursor???

Comment: Try adding `android:cursorVisible="true"` for the edittext..

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color/7238526#7238526)

Comment: cursorVisible did not help me.

Comment: Try the answer in the above given link..

Comment: Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to `@null` should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Comment: Have you tried it @birdy??

Comment: There are a few options in Lal's provided link.  Another is the one that specifies a drawable "color_cursor" and then provides `textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"`.  @birdy I recommend you check out your options.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"` and `android:textColor`

Do it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a template"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
```