# how to make cursor black in android

Tags: java, android

I make a simple demo of auto complete .it is working fine I need some issue in UI .

Please check image as autosuggest look..

here is my code ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="@string/chooseStation"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_buttonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/okButton" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Major concern is this code :

```
   <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Actually first problem is that my cursor become white it is not visible .secondly how to make rectangle in text field so that it look good.in my view it show only base line .Thirdly how to give padding so that it not touch end point of width ..

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set EditText cursor color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to @null

Then, the cursor will have the `android:textColor` value as color.