# How to show the cursor color in edit text in kitkat?

Tags: android, android-layout

the cursor is not display in 4.4 in Edit text.
My code is below of the xml :

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editextTitle"
                style="@style/WrapMid_edittext"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: Explain your issue more specific

Comment: android:textCursorDrawable="@null" Use this in xml file

Comment: do you want to change the cursor color.

Comment: Thanks @PrashantMaheshwariAndro it works for me..

Answer (score 1):

To change cursor color you need to create a drawable as below (cursor.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid android:color="@color/cursor_color" />

<size android:width="1dp" />
```

and use it as

```
                <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editextTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/WrapMid_edittext"
                android:hint="Search"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is very general, you should be more specific but I guess that I understood what you meant in that question.

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

Add this simple line and it should fix your problem. You could trick with this code and change the colour of the cursor as you prefer.

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html) if you want a reference guide and if you scroll down, I'd invite you to focus on this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your edit text should be like this

```
          <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editextTitle"
            style="@style/WrapMid_edittext"
            android:hint="Search"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Still facing the problem .. look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)