# How to style the EditText widget in a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, user-interface

Have just begun styling and theming an app.

I have many `EditText`s in `TextInputLayout`s in an `AppCompatActivity`.

[image]

My questions are:

- Not sure what the line (the blue line above) in the `EditText` widget is called, just referring it as 'ruler'. How can the rulers (invisible above), be made visible, and in any custom color. Presently, the ruler shows only on tapping the `EditText`.
- The `EditText` cursor does not show, how can it be made visible?
- How can the button 'Add' above be customized regarding its background color and text color?
- How can the focus be set to the first `EditText` initially?
- How can the `TextInputLayout`'s hint color be changed after it shrinks and flies to the top? (Presently, blue.)
- Is the default Android font `Roboto`? How can I change the font to anything that's available out there, 'real quick'?

Greatly appreciate any help or pointers.

Corresponding code fragments:

**`Layout`** file

```
            <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pocLabel"
            style="@style/DialogLabelColor"
            android:text="Business Owner"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilPOCFName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pocLabel">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/POCFName"
                style="@style/InputDialogText"
                android:hint="First name (REQUIRED)"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilPOCLName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tilPOCFName"
            android:textColor="#000000">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/POCLName"
                style="@style/InputDialogText"
                android:hint="Last name"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**`styles.xml`**

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here
    -->

</style>

<style name="activated" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>
<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="MyThemeNavy" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle</item>

</style>

<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle." parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">#FFF</item>
</style>

<style name="InfoDlgTextLHS" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
</style>
<style name="InputDialogText" parent="MyThemeNavy">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
</style>
<style name="InfoDlgTextRHS" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
</style>
<style name="DialogLabelColor" parent="MyThemeNavy">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_list_text_color_inverse</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
<style name="MyThemeNavy.Dialogs" parent="MyThemeNavy">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/main_list_text_color</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

**`colors.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="primaryColor">#006989</color>
<color name="primaryColorDark">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="accentColor">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorBackground">#B1C1C0</color>
<!-- Drawer -->
<color name="mainDrawerBackground">#564639</color>

<!-- Main (non-drawer) lists -->
<color name="commonMainListsBackground">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="main_list_text_color">#000000</color>
<color name="list_item_pressed_color">#CADAFF</color>
<color name="list_item_color">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="drawer_list_item_pressed_color">#E4FDE1</color>
<color name="drawer_list_item_color">@color/mainDrawerBackground</color>
<color name="divider_color">#DFF8EB</color>

<!-- Counters -->
<color name="distance_counter_color">#FE5F55</color>
<color name="deals_counter_color">#388659</color>

<!-- Information dialog -->
<color name="info_content_color">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="primary_material_dark">#9e9e9e</color>
<color name="primary_dark_material_dark">#cad7ff</color>
<color name="accent_material_dark">#3469ff</color>
<color name="background_material_dark">#344055</color>
<color name="foreground_material_dark">#ffffff</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#044389</color>

<!-- Input dialogs -->
<color name="input_dialog_backgroud">#6DAEDB</color>
<color name="main_list_text_color_inverse">#FFFFFF</color>
```

**`AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
        <activity
        android:name=".xxx.xxxCRUActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add"
        android:theme="@style/MyThemeNavy.Dialogs">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Thank you!

Comment: IF you want to change Hiint color of text input layout change color of colorAccent in color.xml file.

Comment: Post your your complete style.xml, color.xml and layoutfile here.

Comment: Thanks @ChiragSavsani. Posted the complete `colors` and `styles` XML. My layout file is way too big for this post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding your `TextInputLayout`, create a style for it

```
<style name="InputLayout" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
    </style>
```

This gives you some flexibility for styling the `AppCompatEditText`. Don't forget to add the style to the `TextInputLayout`.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/InputLayout">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Niels Masdorp. Getting an exception though, upon using your suggestion:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)`

Not sure why. My activity, in the Manifest, is using a custom theme (code above). Is this error because of that?

Comment: My mistake, the above exception. The widget was `EditText` instead of `AppCompatEditText`.

Comment: +1 for your suggestion, @Niels Masdorp:  the hint color styling works. Not sure what the `colorControl` attributes are doing, though. Are they for the ruler?

Comment: From [Set EditText cursor color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color) :

`<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>`

Works!

Comment: I'm sure there are more attributes, these are only the ones I've worked with. Glad to have helped! Maybe split up your questions to get better response to the rest of them? I might take a look later though.

Comment: What if i just want to change only color of "(REQUIRED)" is it possible ?
Actually, i want to put start in Red color. .! how can i achieve with TextInputLayout ?