# Change EditText Cursor color through styles.xml

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

Right now, I can change the cursor drawable through reflection and using property `android:textCursorDrawable`. I looked at the `TextView` code, and its actually reading the drawables from Resources.Theme. I'm wondering if its possible and how to change it by creating a custom theme in `styles.xml`?

```
 final Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
 /*
  * Look the appearance up without checking first if it exists because
  * almost every TextView has one and it greatly simplifies the logic
  * to be able to parse the appearance first and then let specific tags
  * for this View override it.
  */

 TypedArray a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextViewAppearance, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set EditText cursor color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

Answer (score 4):

In your layout do the following :

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"/>
```

Then create drawalble cursor_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> // Set your required color code for your cursor color
</shape>
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 3):

Edittext has an attribute called **android:textCursorDrawable** , 
set this attribute to **@null**
now you can set any desired color to **android:textColor**, 
this will result in your cursor color change.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your drawable folder.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:width="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

and define this tag in EditText tag:

```
 android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your EditText properties, there is an attribute: `android:textCursorDrawable`.

Now set it to `@null` like this:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

So now your EditText Cursor is same as your EditText TextColor.

Answer (score 0):

Change the color anytime you want in your project at res->values->colors.xml named "colorAccent". This applies to all Edit Text as default color, and supports all API Versions.