# How to change coloring aspects of default editText Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I cannot figure out how to change the default coloring of editText from pink to blue. I managed to change the underline using:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
```

Here is my current XML for me editText box

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:text="@string/customword"
android:ems="10"
android:id="@+id/customword"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:tint="@color/blue"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textColorLink="@color/blue"  //no affect
android:textColorHint="@color/blue" //no affect
android:textColorHighlight="@color/blue" //no affect
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

Here are some screenshots for the aspects I want to change from pink:
enter image description here

[Pink Bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWJRv.png)

[Pink Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9KiY.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set EditText cursor color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor (and bubble) color should match your [`colorAccent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#colorAccent), so set your accent color to the color you would like to use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Or, if you would prefer to only change the accent color for the `EditText`, you can use a theme overlay:

```
<style name="AppTheme.EditTextOverlay" parent = "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Then apply it to your `EditText`:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/customword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/customword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.EditTextOverlay" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color), does this solve your issue?

> Setting the android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null should result in the use of android:textColor as the cursor color.