# How to set a cursor in android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText on touch?

Tags: android

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_number"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/image_delete"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
                    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
                    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"

                    />
```

this is my android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText i want to show  cursor when i tap on any charter of edittext right side of charter   i tried with

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

this property but still not not showing cursor please suggest me how i will achieve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165217/8089770

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work fine

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/test"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"

    />
```

> @drawable/test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#d20d0d"  />
</shape>
```

Comment: still currsor is not coming suppose i have enter 88274983 and i tap on between 7 and 4 then it should display curssor

Comment: @AnilThakur did u remove `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`

Comment: i have just replace your given xml  but the given xml not getting solution

Comment: @AnilThakur the above code working fine in my device

Comment: yes i have remove selectAllOnFocus=true is it requred

Comment: @AnilThakur not required

Comment: i don't know why cursor is not coming in my device when i tap on cursor   on  any text  it should tap on that single currsor in my case double case is working but single currsor is not working