# android- how to change edittext wink line

Tags: android, android-edittext

as you see,we have a wink line in edittext when it gets the focus .
I want to change the line color /

I mean the blue line in this image :

[image]

How can I change its color ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set EditText cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

Answer (score 1):

Wink line is technically called cursor. It's color can be with the help of attribute `android:textCursorDrawable`. Or if you want to have the text and cursor color to be same you can set textCursorDrawable to null as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)