# EditText not showing cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I'm trying to display the cursor in an EditText by adding

```
 android:cursorVisible="true"
```

in the xml. The issue is that the app version written for a full touch device that use softKeyboard display the cursor but i've developed the app also for devices with physical keyboard and when i'm hidding the softkeyboard the cursor is not even visible.

So the question is how can i make the cursor visible?

For example here is my xml file of an custom Alert and even here the cursor is not showed.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Site:"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <EditText
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/site"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#2323"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#232323"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/site"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="User:"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <EditText
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:id="@+id/editUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textUser"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#2323"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="#232323"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pswFtp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editUser"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Password:"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <EditText
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/editPswFtp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#2323"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pswFtp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#232323"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editPswFtp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#232323"
        android:text="SALVA"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Share your layout.xml with question

Comment: @NileshRathod added xml

Comment: your code is working fine for me kindly check your theme color

Comment: @NileshRathod in my Java i have this parameters set to EditText      editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);

Comment: @NileshRathod so you have to try it without SoftKeyboard

Comment: Remove `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`

Comment: @NileshRathod i have to use it as i have a device with physical keyboard, without it it will open softkeyboard that i doesn't need

Comment: than try to set custom cursor in your editText like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color

Comment: @NileshRathod yet tryed it, and even this doesn't work

Comment: `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`

Comment: SOLVED by using editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false); instead of .setInputType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

Instead of

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create your custom one that would be visible.

In the `res/drawable` make your `custom_cursor.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</shape>
```

and then add it to your `EditText`

```
 android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_cursor"
```

You can select your own colors and size of the cursor.

Comment: It doesn't work, as i'm using in my java      editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true); so the cursor is not viewed anyway

Comment: @JohnKarry Why you are using `editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);` ? because you set Input Type **NULL** in your java code due to that cursor not showing up. If you remove/ comment that line then cursor must be start showing.

Comment: @AnkitKumarSingh  _i've developed the app also for devices with physical keyboard and when i'm hidding the softkeyboard the cursor is not even visible._