# Customizing TextInputLayout and EditText in android studio

Tags: android, xml

I have these two `TextInputLayout` and I want to change colors.

[image: Customzing this two TextInputLayout in android]

I want to change **color Accent** to **color Violet** (like two violet lines).

and how to change cursor color ??

and this is my `XML` code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/amount_lyt"
    android:layout_width="0.0dp"
    android:layout_height="0.0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10.0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline61"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline60">

    <ir.jetservice.customviews.AVEditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/amount"
        android:text="10,000"
        android:textSize="15.0sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/account_lyt"
    android:layout_width="0.0dp"
    android:layout_height="0.0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10.0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline62"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline61">

    <ir.jetservice.customviews.AVEditText
        android:id="@+id/account"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/account_number"
        android:textSize="15.0sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> Note: `AVEditText` is a normal `EditText`, it just changes **English** numbers to **Persian**.

Comment: @ModiHarsh thanks your answer was helpful. If you want this, first upvote my question. (15 reputations for upvote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're changing the Cursor color then see this solution: [Change `EditText` Cursor color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color)

For changing it's line color you've to add theme in `styles.xml` and appply that theme to the `EditText`.

**Add theme in `styles`** :

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yourColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourColor</item>
</style>
```

**Apply theme to the `EditText`** :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/amount_lyt"
    android:layout_width="0.0dp"
    android:layout_height="0.0dp"
    android:layout_margin="10.0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline61"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline60">

    <ir.jetservice.customviews.AVEditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="@string/amount"
        android:text="10,000"
        android:textColor="@color/yourColor"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
        android:textSize="15.0sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the colors located in res/values/styles

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#49C0D8</item>
```

Comment: how to do this? write what? please give me more pieces of information.

Comment: @ShahradElahi the file is generated by default you need to change the hexadecimal of the color

Comment: I found `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>` and removed that and color changed to **Green**. btw i aleary have `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorViolet</item>` code inside style file.

Comment: It chaged to green since the #49C0D8 is green use https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp to get the hex of the color you need

Comment: The colorPrimaryDark is used when the phone is set to dark mode